# I want to run the function in the bot again if the condition does not match

Tags: python, bots, telegram-bot, aiogram

I have this func:

```
@dp.message_handler(state=StateInfo.user_answer)
async def reset_bot(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.reset_state(True)
    if message.text == 'Send new task':
        await start_uma(message)
    else:
        await bot.send_message(text="Error!", chat_id=message.chat.id)
        await reset_bot(message, state)
```

But after running this year I get endless error messages
I've tried using the get_updetes and loops but nothing seems to work. Please tell me what I did wrong

Comment: Be more clear, what have you tried? what is the error? what help do you want from us?

Comment: I want that when the "else" block is executed, the function is started on a new one and works with a new message.
I have tried using the method bot.get_updates to get new data

Comment: So you want `await start_uma(message)`  in the else block as well?

Comment: No, I want to restart func in "else" block. but i have infinite function

Comment: What you mean by _restart func_? Do you want to restart the state of the bot?

Comment: I want that if the user enters the wrong value, then the function is called again and waits for the correct answer

Comment: If you remove `await reset_bot(message, state)` you won't get _get endless error messages_ . Your recursive function is wrong, as you are calling the `reset_bot` with the same wrong message in the else block and it goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: How to do it right?

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive function is wrong, as you are calling the `reset_bot` with the same wrong message in the else block and it goes into an infinite loop.

**Code:**

```
def validate_text(text):
    if text == 'Send new task':
        return True
    else:
        return False


# Check for valid text
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: not validate_text(message.text), state=state=StateInfo.user_answer)
async def process_text_invalid(message: types.Message):
    """
    If text is invalid
    """
    return await message.reply("Text gotta be a wrong.\nRetry again with valid text.")    


@dp.message_handler(lambda message: validate_text(message.text), state=state=StateInfo.user_answer)
async def reset_bot(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
"""
If text is valid
"""
    await state.reset_state(True)
    await start_uma(message)

    # or finish conversation
    # await state.finish()
```

I took reference from an [official example from doc](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html).